# Why is META-INF folder is empty?

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger-ui

Not having the META-INF file for me is a pretty big deal because I'm using Swagger UI and it adds META-INF to resource handlers.

Pom file:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        ...
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${maven-war-plugin.mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And here's my `src/main/resources` folder:

```
resources
--application.properties
--logback--spring.xml
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, this is all I get from my target folder:

```
target
--classes
--project-1.0-SNAPSHOT
--generated-sources
--generated-test-sources
--maven-archiver
--maven-status
--surefire-reports
--test-classes
--project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
--project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.original
```

I'm really confused as to why my manifest file isn't being generated. I checked in target inside `--project-1.0-SNAPSHOT` and I saw 2 directories META-INF and WEB-INF (besides other generated stuff). WEB-INF contains all the classes, lib, and views. META-INF is absolutely empty.

I checked my `application.properties` file and I didn't see any properties that altered resource paths whatsoever.

Comment: It should be in `classes` as it is part of the classpath. A WAR has 2 locations fo the `META-INF`.

Comment: @M.Deinum not there unfortunately.

Comment: Also why should it be generated? You are also overriding the war plugin which spring boot already does for you. Also why would you need it? That being said, if you have a `META-INF` in your `src/main/resources` it will be copied to the `WEB-INF/classes` directory (where it should reside). If nothing is generated or put in there it will be left out. So I'm still not sure why you think it is an issue.

Comment: Swagger-UI references it as a resource location - `classpath:/META-INF/resources/`. Because it's missing, there is no swagger-ui. The `annotationProcessorPaths` configuration in `maven-compiler-plugin` simply cannot be removed. We make use of Criteria API with the annotations generated by that configuration. Removing it would mean a lot of refactoring. We need it in the project. Now, you mentioned that we should have a `META-INF` in our `src/main/resources`. Well strange thing is I don't see one. Any idea what could be wrong? How can we "generate" the `META-INF` inside `src/main/resources`?

Comment: You can just create a directory. Also if swagger needs it swagger should create it. So either you forgot to configure something for swagger or you forgot to add needed things to your code for swagger.